# Chainerで学習時にエラーが出てしまい、学習できない

Tags: python, chainer

初めて利用します。
私は、chainerを利用してConvolutionalLSTMという機構を用いた機械学習の研究を行っております。

MovingMnistを利用した実験ではプログラムが動いたのですが、手持ちのデータを利用しようとした所エラーが出てしまい、困っております。
入力データは、320x256のbmpデータ(1チャンネル)になります。

**エラー内容**

```
/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

Exception in main training loop: Unsupported dtype object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 299, in run
    update()
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updater.py", line 223, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updater.py", line 228, in update_core
    in_arrays = self.converter(batch, self.device)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 93, in concat_examples
    [example[i] for example in batch], padding[i])))
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 35, in to_device
    return cuda.to_gpu(x, device)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 275, in to_gpu
    return _array_to_gpu(array, device_, stream)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 322, in _array_to_gpu
    return cupy.asarray(array)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/creation/from_data.py", line 61, in asarray
    return core.array(a, dtype, False)
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2070, in cupy.core.core.array
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2101, in cupy.core.core.array
Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 81, in <module>
    train()
  File "train.py", line 69, in train
    trainer.run()
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 313, in run
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 299, in run
    update()
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updater.py", line 223, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updater.py", line 228, in update_core
    in_arrays = self.converter(batch, self.device)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 93, in concat_examples
    [example[i] for example in batch], padding[i])))
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 35, in to_device
    return cuda.to_gpu(x, device)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 275, in to_gpu
    return _array_to_gpu(array, device_, stream)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 322, in _array_to_gpu
    return cupy.asarray(array)
  File "/home/denko/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/creation/from_data.py", line 61, in asarray
    return core.array(a, dtype, False)
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2070, in cupy.core.core.array
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2101, in cupy.core.core.array
ValueError: Unsupported dtype object
```

**コード**

--dataset_for_rr--

```
import numpy as np
import chainer
from PIL import Image
from chainer import cuda, Variable

class rrDataset(chainer.dataset.DatasetMixin):
    def __init__(self,l,r,inf,outf):
        self.rr_list = np.load('/media/denko/OS/data/rr_list/test.npy')
        self.l = l
        self.r = r
        self.inf = inf
        self.outf = outf
        self.flames = self.inf + self.outf
        self.num = self.r - self.l
        self.xp = cuda.cupy

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num

    def get_example(self,i):
        self.ind = self.l + i
        self.data = np.empty((self.flames,1,256,320),dtype=np.float32)

        for j in range(self.flames):
            self.bmp_name = str(int(self.rr_list[self.ind][j]))
            self.year = self.bmp_name[0:4]
            self.month = self.bmp_name[4:6]
            self.path = '/media/denko/OS/data/bmp/' + self.year + '/' + self.month + '/' + self.bmp_name + '.bmp'
            self.bmp_data = Image.open(self.path)
            self.bmp_data = np.array(self.bmp_data).astype(dtype=np.float32)
            self.bmp_data = self.bmp_data / 255
            self.data[j,0,:,:] = self.bmp_data

        self.data = Variable(np.array(self.data,dtype=np.float32))

        return self.data[:self.inf,0,:,:], self.data[self.inf:self.flames,0,:,:]
```

Comment: `Unsupported dtype object` というエラーメッセージから察するに、`rrDataset.get_example()` メソッドで numpy.array のインスタンスを chainer.Variable のインスタンスに変換している部分(`self.data = Variable(np.array(...))`)に問題がある様に思えます。

Answer (score 1):

短く言えば，

```
 34         self.data = Variable(np.array(self.data,dtype=np.float32))
```

を

```
 34         self.data = np.array(self.data,dtype=np.float32)
```

とすればよいでしょう．

以下は詳細です．
わかりにくかったので行をつけさせていただきました．

```
  1 import numpy as np
  2 import chainer
  3 from PIL import Image
  4 from chainer import cuda, Variable
  5
  6 class rrDataset(chainer.dataset.DatasetMixin):
  7     def __init__(self,l,r,inf,outf):
  8         self.rr_list = np.load('/media/denko/OS/data/rr_list/test.npy')
  9         self.l = l
 10         self.r = r
 11         self.inf = inf
 12         self.outf = outf
 13         self.flames = self.inf + self.outf
 14         self.num = self.r - self.l
 15         self.xp = cuda.cupy
 16
 17     def __len__(self):
 18         return self.num
 19
 20     def get_example(self,i):
 21         self.ind = self.l + i
 22         self.data = np.empty((self.flames,1,256,320),dtype=np.float32)
 23
 24         for j in range(self.flames):
 25             self.bmp_name = str(int(self.rr_list[self.ind][j]))
 26             self.year = self.bmp_name[0:4]
 27             self.month = self.bmp_name[4:6]
 28             self.path = '/media/denko/OS/data/bmp/' + self.year + '/' + self.month + '/' + self.bmp_name + '.bmp'
 29             self.bmp_data = Image.open(self.path)
 30             self.bmp_data = np.array(self.bmp_data).astype(dtype=np.float32)
 31             self.bmp_data = self.bmp_data / 255
 32             self.data[j,0,:,:] = self.bmp_data
 33
 34         self.data = Variable(np.array(self.data,dtype=np.float32))
 35
 36         return self.data[:self.inf,0,:,:], self.data[self.inf:self.flames,0,:,:]
```

問題はmetropolis氏が指摘しているように，34行目でVaribleを返しているところです．DatasetMixinは通常np.ndarrayまたはnp.ndarrayのタプルを返すことが想定されています．

検証用に短いコードを示します．

```
  1 from chainer.dataset.convert import concat_examples
  2 from chainer import Variable
  3 import numpy as np
  4
  5 data_np_1 = np.arange(9, dtype=np.float32).reshape((3, 3))
  6 data_np_2 = data_np_1 * 2
  7 data_Variable_1 = Variable(data_np_1)
  8 data_Variable_2 = Variable(data_np_2)
  9
 10 batch_1_np = (data_np_1[:1, :], data_np_1[1:, :])
 11 batch_2_np = (data_np_2[:1, :], data_np_2[1:, :])
 12
 13 batch_1_Variable = (data_Variable_1[:1, :], data_Variable_1[1:, :])
 14 batch_2_Variable = (data_Variable_2[:1, :], data_Variable_2[1:, :])
 15
 16 print(concat_examples([batch_1_np, batch_2_np]))
 17 print(concat_examples([batch_1_Variable, batch_2_Variable]))
 18
```

結果が以下のようになります．

```
  (
  array([
          [[0., 1., 2.]],
          [[0., 2., 4.]]
        ], dtype=float32),
  array([
          [[ 3.,  4.,  5.], [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],
          [[ 6.,  8., 10.], [12., 14., 16.]]
        ], dtype=float32)
)

(
  array([
          [[variable(0.), variable(1.), variable(2.)]],
          [[variable(0.), variable(2.), variable(4.)]]
        ], dtype=object),
  array([
          [[variable(3.), variable(4.), variable(5.)], [variable(6.), variable(7.), variable(8.)]],
          [[variable(6.), variable(8.), variable(10.)], [variable(12.), variable(14.), variable(16.)]]
        ], dtype=object)
)
```

このように，dtypeがobjectであるndarrayが生成されているため，
ValueError: Unsupported dtype object
と言われるわけです．

これは`chainer.dataset.convert._concat_arrays`内で，

```
if not isinstance(arrays[0], numpy.ndarray) and\
   not isinstance(arrays[0], cuda.ndarray):
    arrays = numpy.asarray(arrays)
```

が呼ばれており，numpy.asarrayにVariableを渡すと，返り値が通常のndarrayにならないことが原因です．

以下はTipsなので，読み飛ばしていただいても結構です．

`inf`はmathでInfinityを表す予約語です．使わないことが推奨されます．
同様に`.data`属性はnumpyとcupyでメモリへのポインタを表す予約語, Chainerでxp.ndarrayを表す予約語なので，自分では使わないことが推奨されます．(実際にはChainerではv3.0.0以降予約語から解除されていますが，これはnumpy, cupyとの予約語の競合を避けたためです)

Comment: metropolis様、Yuki Hashimoto様、ご返答ありがとうございます。　後ほど改めてコメントさせていただきます。（不慣れなもので、評価システムに関して変なことをしてしまったかもしれません…）

Comment: 先ほどこちらの部分を書き換え、その他部分にも修正を入れました所、無事動かすことができました。お二人とも、本当にありがとうございます。